# PHP text input to .txt file

Tags: php, html

I tried to make a simple PHP program that writes text from an input field and puts it in a .txt file. What is wrong with my code? It doesn't leave spaces between items and copies the previous item and doubles it. The file is called email.txt . Here is the code:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
            $name = $_POST['name'];
            $file = fopen("email.txt", "r+") or die("<h1>Eroarea 1</h1>"); //In caz ca fisierul nu este gasit
            $s = fread($file, filesize("email.txt"));
            $s = $name . "\n";
            fputs($file, $s) or die("<h1>Eroarea 2</h1>"); //In caz ca server-ul nu poate fi contactat
            fclose($file);
            echo "<h1></h1>";
    } ?>            

<section id="five" class="wrapper style2 special fade">
                <div class="container">
                    <header>
                        <h2>Writer</h2>
                        <p>Put text here</p>
                    </header>
                    <form method="post" action="#" class="container 50%" onSubmit="post">
                        <div class="row uniform 50%">
                            <div class="8u 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Email" /></div>
                            <div class="4u$ 12u$(xsmall)"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="fit special" /></div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </section>
```

Comment: Can you show us what you would like the file to look like

Comment: Let's say I send 5 different inputs: 1,2,3,4,5. I want the file to write them like this: 
1
2
3
4
5
Each on a separate row

Answer (score 0):

A much easier way to append content to a file would be to use [file_put_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    file_put_contents('email.txt', $name . PHP_EOL, FILE_APPEND);
} 
?>
```

That will create the file if it doesn't exist and append to it if it does.

Comment: And where do I put that? I am new to PHP, and this is just my first try to it

Comment: @StefanDoncean - Updated the example. It basically replaces all your current file handling code.

Comment: Ok. It works. It repaired the duplication problem. What about the spaces between the inputs? Still , I can't figure it out...

Comment: @StefanDoncean - You need to be more specific. In your question you stated _"1 2 3 4 5 Each on a separate row"_. This does just that, gives you each on a separate row.

Comment: I tried, but for me it doesn't do it. I will try to figure it out, but I don't know why it doesn't.

Comment: If you open the file, aren't the names on separate rows? I updated the code to use `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\n"`. Also, if you're on Windows and open it in Notepad, the newlines might not show correctly.